# Why am I unable to get the output when I try to enter only three elements in an array of size four or more?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[4],i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to enter only 3 numbers, I was expecting to get those 3 numbers as the output.

Edit:
How can I make this array flexible, like, if I'm not really sure like, how many elements I am going to add in it, but I know that it will have less than 4 or maybe 5 elements?

Comment: Your code requires input 4 numbers.

Comment: I suspect that you entered three numbers on a single line and expected the end-of-line to signal end-of-input. If that is the case, that's not how it works; with `>>`, line breaks count as whitespace separators and the program keeps waiting for you to input the fourth number.

Comment: how do you expect the code to know that you want only 3 numbers as input not 4 ?

Comment: How are you expecting only three numbers when both of your loops go round four times? Your program will always do exactly what you tell it to do, not magically do what you want it to do. Since your program says loop until four numbers have been input, then what is happening when you only enter three is that the program is waiting for the fourth number to be input. That's why you don't see any output.

Answer (score 1):

Use getline with cin and check for an empty string so that you can break out of the for loop, I've also kept count of the total numbers entered so only those that you entered are finally displayed.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int a[4] = {}, i, totalnumbers=0;
   for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      string input = "";
      getline(cin, input);
      if (input == "")
      {
         break;
      }

      a[i] = atoi(input.c_str());
      totalnumbers++;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < totalnumbers; i++) {
      cout << a[i] << " ";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use `std::stoi` or `strtol` instead of `atoi` because `atoi` silently fails.

Comment: Note that this code requires each number to be on its own line.  You can use a `std::istringstream` if you want to allow reading multiple numbers from a single line.